# Css z-index not working correctly with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have a block of code that is solid.  Works fine. Except for the footer of my site.  No idea why but the heading bars are not showing for the footer but they are everywhere else?

here is a pen of the working code
http://codepen.io/VincentStephens/pen/EjyJKP

Here is a screenshot of the not working site:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3oxrvzvdvyaai6/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-19%20at%2019.07.47.png?dl=0

This works by creating a :before element. Putting the menu text into a span, then using z-index to position the span on top of the :before.

You can see the element there (see photo), everything is the same but just won't show unless I change the z-index to 0 or higher but then the line is above the heading text in the span???

```
h1.heading {
    color: $light-gold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    span {
        background-color: $golden-black;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}

h1.heading:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: $light-gold;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML - working

```
<h1 class="heading"><span>The Team</span></h1>
```

HTML - Footer, not working

```
<div class="fluid-container footer">
    <footer class="container">

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1 class="heading"><span>About</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Bestiarum vero nullum iudicium puto. Quasi vero, inquit, perpetua oratio rhetorum solum, non etiam philosophorum sit. Quae sunt igitur communia vobis cum antiquis, iis sic utamur quasi concessis; De illis, cum volemus. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Huic mori optimum esse propter desperationem sapientiae, illi propter spem vivere.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1 class="heading"><span>Address</span></h1>
            <p class="address">
                address<br>
            </p>

            <p class="address">
                Tell: 0207 374 6141 <br>    
                Email: <a href="">enquiries@company.com</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h1 class="heading"><span>Connect</span></h1>
            <img src="img/social-media.png" width="186" height="46">

            <h1>Payment Options</h1>
            <img src="img/payment-cards.png" width="267" height="56">
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML and the uncompiled CSS? Looks like you're missing the HTML from this question entirely and like you are using Sass or something. "Code problem" questions on Stack Overflow have to include enough code to reproduce the issue in the question, or they will be closed.

Comment: Anyway, why don't you just use `::after` instead of `::before`? That way you still get the same effect but it starts *after* the text rather than *before* it, so it won't be going *through* the text.

Comment: You mention it works well except for the footer.  Do you have an `h1` in your footer? (sorry but I need to ask since you did not post the HTML for the section where it is not working)

Comment: It would be the same effect to put it after or before.  I need a responsive 100% width for the element so either way it goes through the text. Unless you know another way?

Comment: `z-index` only applies to `positioned` elements. So `h1.heading span` needs to have `position: relative;` or `fixed` or `absolute` (basically anything but the default `static` position) applied to it. Maybe the pseudo-element, too. See http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: I had heard about the positioning, lets just check to see if I forgot to add it to both elements

Comment: Well, then it shouldn't work on the pen either, right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the moment on sanity.... it was indeed a position issue.

The footer also has a background colour. so that entire element needed to have a `position: relative; and z-index: -1;` added to it.

full code for anyone else in same situation:

SCSS - wil need compiling

```
.fluid-container.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: $light-golden-black;
    footer {
        h1.heading {
            color: $light-gold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 40px;
            font-family: SourceSansPro;
            position: relative;
            span {
                background-color: $light-golden-black;
                display: inline-block;
                z-index: 1;
                padding-right: 10px;
                position: relative;
            }
        }

        h1.heading:before {
            content: "";
            background-color: $light-gold;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 23px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 6px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
}
```